# How to make a checkbox look like a button when checkboxes are in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

My checkboxes are autogenerated as a list so I can not change that and I have tried do modify css code I have found while searching but I can not get it to work properly.
I want to make my checkboxes look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/2/) but instead they look like this

```css
.chk-btn>li {
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}

.chk-btn>li label {
    float: left;
    width: 4.0em;
}

.chk-btn>li label {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    display: block;
}

.chk-btn>li label input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
}

.chk-btn>li input:checked {
    background-color: #911;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-content">
  <form>
    <div>
      <ul class="chk-btn">
        <li>
          <label for="con-1">
            choice1
          </label>
          <input id="con-1" name="con" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="con-2">
            choice2
          </label>
          <input id="con-2" name="con" type="checkbox" value="2">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="con-3">
            choice3
          </label>
          <input id="con-3" name="con" type="checkbox" value="3">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="con-4">
            choice4
          </label>
          <input id="con-4" name="con" type="checkbox" value="4">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

How do I get it right?

And also have a them change to darker color when hover?

Comment: because the fiddle does not stlye the checkbox (input) itself as a button but the span which is inside the label. The input (checkbox) itself is hidden. you only see the label. PS: Also dont use float for styling purpose. `input`and `label` are inline-level elements. The will be displayed inline by default.

Comment: Can I not make this work without a span?

Comment: no you can style the label directly. however in anycase you should hide the checkbox: `input[type="checkbox"] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the `input` and usage of `label` and `+` selector based on `input` **checked** or **hover** state is really helpful for such a scenario. I have removed css which was not needed and also switched position of `input` and `label` tags with each other for `+` to work like so :-

```css
.chk-btn>li {
    display:inline-flex;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow: auto;
}


.chk-btn>li label {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    width: 4.0em;
}

.chk-btn>li input {
    display: none;
}

.chk-btn>li input:checked + label {
    background-color: #911;
    color: #fff;
}

.chk-btn>li input:hover + label {
    background-color: #580716;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-content">
  <form>
    <div>
      <ul class="chk-btn">
        <li>
                  <input id="con-1" name="con" type="checkbox" value="1">
          <label for="con-1">
            choice1
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
                  <input id="con-2" name="con" type="checkbox" value="2">
          <label for="con-2">
            choice2
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
              <input id="con-3" name="con" type="checkbox" value="3">
          <label for="con-3">
            choice3
          </label>
    
        </li>
        <li>
                  <input id="con-4" name="con" type="checkbox" value="4">
          <label for="con-4">
            choice4
          </label>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```